# Select pandas dataframe columns based on which names contain strings in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df`, and a list of strings, `cols_needed`, which indicate the columns I want to retain in `df`. The column names in `df` do not exactly match the strings in `cols_needed`, so I cannot directly use something like `intersection`. But the column names do contain the strings in `cols_needed`. I tried playing around with `str.contains` but couldn't get it to work. How can I subset `df` based on `cols_needed`?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sim-prod1': [1,2],
    'sim-prod2': [3,4],
    'sim-prod3': [5,6],
    'sim_prod4': [7,8]
})

cols_needed = ['prod1', 'prod2']

# What I want to obtain:
    sim-prod1  sim-prod2
0      1        3
1      2        4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `regex` option of `filter`

```
df.filter(regex='|'.join(cols_needed))
```

---

```
   sim-prod1  sim-prod2
0          1          3
1          2          4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can explore [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a joint pattern, for example:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(cols_needed))]
```

Output:

```
   sim-prod1  sim-prod2
0          1          3
1          2          4
```

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension could work as well:

```
columns = [cols for cols in df 
           for col in cols_needed 
           if col in cols]

['sim-prod1', 'sim-prod2']

In [110]: df.loc[:, columns]
Out[110]: 
   sim-prod1  sim-prod2
0          1          3
1          2          4
```

Comment: Nice, or just `df[columns]` in this case